# Let $D_1,D_2\subseteq X$ dense and $f\colon D_1\to D_2$ a homeomorphism. Is there a homeomorphism $F\colon X\to X$ that extends $f$ in both ways?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I've been trying, unsuccessfully, to demonstrate this even supposing that $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff space in virtue of the next theorem (3.2.1) of Engelking's "General Topology" (p.136-137):

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ be a dense subspace of a topological space $X$ and $f$ a continuous mapping of $A$ to a compact space $Y$. The mapping $f$ has a continuous extension over $X$ if and only if for every pair $B_1, B_2$ of disjoint closed subsets of $Y$ the inverse images $f^{-1}[B_1]$ and $f^{-1}[B_2]$ have disjoint closures in the space $X$.

In this context, I can reformulate my question in terms of compactifications: Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space and $Y$ a compact $T_2$ space. If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\colon X\to Y$ are embbedings such that $\alpha_1[X]$ and $\alpha_2[X]$ are dense in $Y$, *i. e.* $\alpha_1 X$ and $\alpha_2 X$ are the same topological space, so are $\alpha_1 X$ and $\alpha_2 X$ equivalent compactifications of $X$?

Does anyone knows a solution or a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a counterexample in the case that $X$ is compact and Hausdorff.

Let $X=\big\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\sqrt{x^2-(y-1)^2}=1\vee\sqrt{x^2-(y+1)^2}=1\big\}$, *i.e.*, the union of the circles with center $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ and radius $1$. Clearly, $X$ is compact with the euclidean topology. Let $D_i=X\setminus\{(0,2),(0,-2)\}$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$. Clearly, $D_i$ is dense in $X$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$. Now, let me define $f\colon D_1\to D_2$ by $$f(x,y)=\Bigg\{\begin{align*}(x,-y)\qquad&\text{if $x\cdot y\geq0$}\\
(-x,y)\qquad&\text{if $x\cdot y\leq0$.}\end{align*}$$ and notice that $f$ is continuous, but if $g\colon X\to X$ is an extension of $f$, then $g$ is neither continuous at $(0,2)$ nor at $(0,-2)$.

Answer (score 2):

What about $X = [0, \infty)$, $D_1 = D_2 = (0, \infty)$, and $f(x) = 1/x$? The only possible extension of $f$ to all of $X$ is by forcing $F(0) = 0$, which fails continuitiy.